# Cómo separar números de una cadena de texto con un split()

Tags: java

Tengo una cadena de texto que vendría siendo la siguiente:

```java
String cadena = "lat/lng: (19.562423432,-94.23432432)";
```

y quiero separar de esa cadena esta parte `"19.562423432,-94.23432432"` para almacenarla en otra variable y que quede así:

```java
cadena2 == "19.562423432,-94.23432432";
```

¿Esto se puede separar con un `split`?

Comment: es una sola cadena que siempre viene con la misma informacion y siempre en las mismas posiciones? si es asi, un split es demasiado.

Comment: Si es en una sola cadena que siempre viene así

Comment: @CarlosHernández - Por favor revisa la edición que realicé, dándole formato al código. Es importante cuidar la forma a la hora de realizar una pregunta. Para formatear código, encontrarás el botón `{  }`.

Answer (score 3):

Ya que se trata de latitudes y longitudes, no puedes correr el riesgo de hacer extracciones basadas en **la cantidad de cifras que haya**, ya que **no todas las latitudes/longitudes tienen la misma cantidad de cifras** y además pueden ser **positivas** o **negativas**.

Podrías tener, por ejemplo:

`-34.8799074,174.7565664`

`19.562423432,-94.23432432`

las dos cadenas tienen valores válidos.

**Una cosa sí es cierta**, las latitudes y longitudes vienen expresadas en un tipo de número (**Double**). Entonces creo que **lo más seguro es trabajar en base al tipo de dato**:

**(1). Si puedes obtener de entrada tu cadena de esta manera
`-34.8799074,174.7565664` :**
Sólo tendrías que crear un array, haciendo split sobre la coma (,) y parsear el valor de tipo `Double` que habrá en cada parte del array:

```
String sCadena=-34.8799074,174.7565664;
String[] s =  sCadena.split(",");
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(s[0]);
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(s[1]);
```

**2. Si indefectiblemente recibes tu cadena como dices en el ejemplo: `"lat/lng: (19.562423432,-94.23432432)"`**

"Limpias" tu cadena, obteniendo lat/long separados por una coma:

```
String str= "lat/lng: (19.562423432,-94.23432432)";
String sCadena = str.substring(str.indexOf("(") + 1, str.indexOf(")"));

// Aquí tendrás en sCadena tus valores limpios:  19.562423432,-94.23432432

// ¿Y si quiero usar mi lat y longitud para algo? Operas como explicado en (1)
String[] s =  sCadena.split(",");
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(s[0]);
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(s[1]);
```

Luego usas tus valores `latitude`, `longitude` como quieras.

**Nota:** Aquí lo importante es que estarás trabajando de acuerdo al tipo de valor de lat/long, por lo que no tendrás error en el resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que tienes que encontrar es donde inicia el subString y donde quieres que termines, sí la cadena que quieres obtener siempre va a venir entre *(   )*, entonces lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
private String obtenerSubString(String cadena)
{
   //Obtienes la posición de inicio y final
   int inicio = cadena.indexOf("(");
   int final = cadena.lastIndexOf(")");
   //inicio+1 pues la función incluye el caracter de dicha posición, final no se le suma nada, pues dicha posición se excluye
   return cadena.substring(inicio+1, final);
}
```

De esta manera, aunque el largo de los valores entre los paréntesis cambien, siempre podrás obtener los valores y así tu método queda genérico para la resolución de tu problema

[Aquí](http://aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=586:estudiando-el-concepto-de-metodo-java-el-metodo-substring-de-la-clase-string-extraer-caracteres-cu00649b&catid=68:curso-aprender-programacion-java-desde-cero&Itemid=188) te dejo información sobre el método substring.

[Aquí](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm) te dejo información sobre indexOf (nota: información en inglés), lastIndexOf, funciona igual, simplemente encuentra la última coincidencia.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución es utilizar `substring` de la siguiente manera:

```
package mx.com.softmolina;

/**
 *
 * @author softmolina
 */
public class split {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String cadena = "lat/lng: (19.562423432,-94.23432432)";
        String cadena2 = cadena.substring(10, 35);
        System.out.println("cadena2: " + cadena2);
    }

}
```

Resultado:

```
  cadena2: 19.562423432,-94.23432432
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Y con `Split` dejado en el comentario por @Mariano http://rextester.com/NSSC67358

Comment: "*tendrías un error `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException` por los paréntesis dentro de la cadena*" <-- No veo cómo el texto puede estar relacionado con el patrón. Creo que estás afirmando algo que es incorrecto.

Comment: Este es un ejemplo que lo prueba http://rextester.com/NSSC67358 (aunque obviamente no lo recomendaría como respuesta a esta pregunta)

Comment: Tienes mucha razón @Mariano mas bien yo estaba poniendo mal la cadena en el split, gracias cada día se aprende algo mas saludos!!

Answer (score -1):

Tal vez puedas utilizar la funcion substring, mas sin embargo, seria bueno que nos comentaras en que lenguaje estas trabajando. C# o Java? por lo del split, presumo que es C#. Confirmarme.

---

Edicion

Confirmado. Para JAVA podrias hacer lo siguiente..

Suponiendo que tienes el codigo `String cadena = "lat/lng:(19.562423432,-94.23432432)";`

y quieres extraer `19.562423432,-94.23432432`

debes utilizar lo siguiente

`cadena.substring(8,24));`

El 8 determina desde donde empieza a cortar la cadena, el 24, hasta donde deberia contar los caracteres.

Espero te haya ayudado

Comment: java tiene split. y OP dijo que era java. Puedes agregar un ejemplo a tu respuesta y ademas para hacer preguntas esta la seccion comentarios. Mas alla de eso, tu respuesta es totalmente correcta.

Comment: Es en java arriba puse la etiqueta xd

Comment: `8, 24` <-- por qué estos valores?

Answer (score -1):

Usando split no podrás hacerlo, ya que split se basa en que pases la expresión regular con la que quieres partir el texto y, en tu caso, no es nada simple.

Sin embargo, mejor que usar substrings y correr el riesgo de encontrarte con un error si hay o deja de haber espacios en blanco, puedes usar expresiones regulares para extraer el valor numérico de la latitud y la longitud en dos variables y, a partir de ahí, hacer con ellas lo que quieras. El código es muy simple y, probablemente, lo puedas mejorar en tu caso particular, pero prefiero dejarlo así por claridad:

```
String regexp = "([\\-?0-9.]+)";
String cadena = "lat/lng:(19.562423432, -94.23432432)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(cadena);
matcher.find(); //Encuentra la primera coincidencia del patron
String lat = matcher.group();
matcher.find(); //Encuentra la segunda coincidencia
String lng = matcher.group();
String resultado= lat.concat(",").concat(lng);
System.out.println(resultado);
```

Espero que te sirva.